# How to get the attribute of a JS object from Java?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, nashorn, jsr223

I know I can use the [Invocable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/script/Invocable.html) class to invoke methods on a class:

```
import javax.script.{ScriptEngine, ScriptEngineManager, Invocable}

val engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js")

val invoker = engine.asInstanceOf[Invocable]

val person = engine.eval(s"""
  new function () {
    this.name = "Rick";
    this.age = 28;
    this.speak = function () {
      return this.name + "-" + this.age;
    }
  };
""")

invoker.invokeMethod(person, "speak") //returns "Rick-28"
```

But, how do I get the `name` attribute of the person? I tried     `invoker.invokeMethod(person, "name")` and I got a `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: I think you will have to "expose" all members you want to share with java part, aka create getters (and optionally setters).

Comment: You can try to assign the person to variable in JavaScript and use `engine.get('person.name')`

Comment: try `person.get("name")`

Comment: @awadheshv: `person` is an `Object`. It does not have `.get`.

Comment: @jcubic  - yes that would work but I don't control the JS source in this case. We can invoke methods from Java, why not access members?

Comment: @Rafouille: I do not have control over the `.js` source unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast person to a [`JSObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/JSObject.html) and then call `person.getMember("name")`. Full Java example:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
                           .getEngineByExtension("js");

JSObject rick = (JSObject) engine.eval("new function () {\n" +
        "            this.name = \"Rick\";\n" +
        "            this.age = 28;\n" +
        "            this.speak = function () {\n" +
        "                return this.name + \"-\" + this.age;\n" +
        "            }\n" +
        "        };");

System.out.println(rick.getMember("name"));
```

Or, if the object is stored in the engine global scope like in the following javascript source:

```
rick = function() {
  this.name= "Rick";
};
```

you can then call

```
engine.eval("rick.name");
```